# MailKit: throws Authentication Failed while calling Authenticate method from the Pop3Client class

Tags: c#, pop3, mailkit, .net-core-3.0

I am using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) for sending and receiving emails. but when I try to get emails, I get the `Authentication Failed` error. here is my code:

```
using MailKit.Net.Pop3;
using MimeKit;

public List<Email> GetEmails()
{
    using var emailClient = new Pop3Client();
    emailClient.Connect("pop.mail.yahoo.com", 995, true);
    emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2"); //commenting this line won't help.
    emailClient.Authenticate("email", "password"); // this line throws 'Authentication Failed' exception.

    var emails = new List<Email>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var message = emailClient.GetMessage(i);
        var emailMessage = new Email
        {
            Content = message.TextBody,
            Subject = message.Subject
        };
        emails.Add(emailMessage);
    }

    return emails;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: stacktrace: `at MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client.<AuthenticateAsync>d__82.MoveNext()    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()   at MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client.Authenticate(Encoding encoding, ICredentials credentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken) `

Comment: `at MailKit.MailService.Authenticate(Encoding encoding, String userName, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at MailKit.MailService.Authenticate(String userName, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this sounds obvious, but the odds are that you're providing the wrong username and/or password. That's what the error is saying.

You can verify this by looking at the log file:

```
var emailClient = new Pop3Client(new ProtocolLogger("pop3.log"))
```

Maybe you can try creating a new Yahoo! Mail account that fails to authenticate just like your real account and give me the username/password for that new account so that I can debug the issue?

Does your username or password contain non-ASCII characters? How about punctuation characters?

If you want me to dig into this, I need to know what the username/password are and what MailKit is sending in case it's sending the wrong strings (pretty sure it's not, but I'll look into it anyway). If you don't give me that info, I can't diagnose the issue.

Comment: thanks @jstedfast, but I was trying it more than 20 times with different values, e.g: 1- user: myId, pass: myPass, 2- myId@yahoo.com, pass: myPass, and more. anyway, I will try it again with other credentials.

Comment: I changed the pass and used a simple one, but the problem still exists.
log file:
`Connected to pops://pop.mail.yahoo.com:995/
S: +OK Hello from jpop-0.1
C: CAPA
S: +OK CAPA list follows
S: IMPLEMENTATION jpop-0.1
S: EXPIRE-NEVER
S: PIPELINING
S: RESP-CODES
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: USER
S: SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2
S: .
C: AUTH PLAIN
S: + 
C: AGVoc20yMDIwADEyMzQ1OTg3NjU=
S: -ERR [SYS/TEMP] Server error - Please try again later.
C: USER ehsm2020
S: +OK Password required.
C: PASS 1234598765
S: -ERR [SYS/TEMP] Server error - Please try again later.`

Comment: The correct format to use for the username string is `username@yahoo.com`. The error you are getting indicates a temporary server error which tells you to try again later. I suggest you follow the directions that the server gave you. You probably triggered some sort of security measure that is blacklisting login attempts for your account because you've exhausted your retry limit.

Comment: that was the first time I tried to connect to my new mail, so I don't think this error is related to the lots of logins. I also try `username@yahoo.com` as I mentioned in the first comment, there is another problem...

Comment: Are you able to login using Thunderbird? I'm betting you can't.

Comment: oh!... there is a security option in the yahoo security section page called `Allow apps that use less secure sign in` . I turned it on and the problem is solved... thanks to @jstedfast